# Question about the proof of residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm currently reading Freitag&Busam's complex analysis and get confused about the proof of residue theorem. The proof assumes the fact that the integral on a smmoth curve of $(z-a)^n$ vanishes when $n<-1$, but I cannot see why this is true.

Since the function would have a singularity at $a$, all the theorems I know do not work. I've searched in this site and someone suggests using Cauchy's Integral Formula, but in my book this formula is only available when we integrate on a circle. I've gone through this book to look for this result but don't find it anywhere.

Can anyone provide a proof for this?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable on an open $U$ then for a curve in $U, \int_C f'(z)dz = f(C(1))-f(C(0))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gamma$ is a closed path and $f$ is differentiable in some neighborhood of $\gamma$ then $\int_{\gamma} f'(z)\, dz=0$. [It doesn't matter if $f$ is not defined at some points inside the path].  You can see this easily using the definition of path integral. Note that $(z-a)^{n} =f'(z)$ where $f(z)=\frac {(z-a)^{n+1}} {n+1}$. Hence the integral is $0$.